# which database for java to store data in memory?

Tags: java, sql, database, orm, nosql

I'm looking for a database which would allow me to store most of the objects in the memory. Basically I want to store in the memory everything except some rarely used data (history of changes, etc).

I'm looking for:

- simple API for java, preferably non-ORM
- ACID is not required (well, D is)
- some support for queries,  but nothing fancy

The idea is to operate on a model in memory, store any "command" mutating the model in the database, periodically synchronize model to database (like prevayler does)

Which database matches my needs? (I'll use postgres or H2 if there isn't anything simpler).

Comment: [hsqldb](http://hsqldb.org)?

Comment: hsqldb is a regular sql database, will give nothing more/simpler than H2/pgsql

Comment: Sqlite? Have you given that a try?

Comment: It's another SQL database - I'd need use some ORM or write tons of SQL queries. I don't want that. I want to say: here database, these are my objects, make sure they are stored and I can load them again in the future if I restart the application. Yes, I used sqlite, hsqldb, oracle, postgres, etc.. I'd prefer something different

Comment: `mongoDB` ? `cassandra` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need one of object databases: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_object_database_management_systems

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Terracotta](http://terracotta.org/).  It is usually used for caching, but its exactly what you are asking for, except that it's "querying" abilities are sparse.

Update:
The previous link was to their "enterprise" edition, but they have the open source project [Ehcache](http://ehcache.org/) which fits your needs, and their enterprise product is based on.

Comment: It does not go well with deep object hierarchies. Does not really look viable, but I'll think about it

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are looking for, but other 'alternative' can be Neo4j, though it might be too much of a time investment and paradigm change.